# How to merge arrays then concat them

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, merge, xmlhttprequest

I retrieved this set of array data from my XMLHttpRequest responseXML object. During Parsing I want to format an array to be passed back to be used.

The array `setup` should go like this

`setup=['eMonth[0]','eDay[0]','holiStr[0]','eMonth[1]','eDay[1],'holiStr[1]'
,'eMonth[2]','eDay[2]','holiStr[2]']`

So I am trying to put setup into an array first then for every setup, concat another setup.

```
function parseXML(xmlData){
var setup;
    for(i=0;i< xmlData.getElementsByTagName('year').length;i++){
        var eYear = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('year')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eMonth = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('month')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eDay = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('day')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eHour = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('hours')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eMinute = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('minutes')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eTitle = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var holiStr = eTitle[i] + '</br>' + eHour[i] + ":" + eMinute[i];
        setup = [eMonth[i],eDay[i],holiStr[i]];
    }   
        return setup;
}
```

This returns empty, i think i messed up. Can some one show me an more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var setup = [];
for(...){
  ...
  setup.push(eMonth[i]);
  setup.push(eDay[i]);
  setup.push(holiStr[i]);
}
return setup;
```

I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to do it like this, but it should meet the requirement that you provided.

Otherwise, keeping objects in your array might be a bit easier to work with down the road, instead of needing to keep "groupings of 3".  I.E.:

```
var setup = [];
for(...){
  ...
  setup.push({eMonth: eMonth[i], eDay: eDay[i], holiStr: holiStr[i]});
}
return setup;
```

... this would allow you to reference `setup[3].eDay`, for example.

Comment: you dont need to use concat()? Most curious to know how to concat and group the same index with each other

Comment: @GivenPie - `concat` is for combining existing arrays together.  I.E., `concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`.  You don't have a setup like this here anywhere that you demonstrated.  Rather, you're just growing an existing array with one-off attributes.  I can provide a way to make this use `concat` if you feel the need, but I don't see it providing any real benefit.

Comment: i need the arrays to concat so I can use to populate a calendar. specific dates on the calendar have indexes defined by (month,day,holiday)

Comment: @GivenPie - I think you need to post more of your code, then, because it is becoming unclear what exactly you're looking to do.  However, I still don't think `concat` is required.  I.E., if your end goal is just an array of these triplets, the code I provided is exactly what you need.  If you need to combine across calls to `parseXML`, then just move `setup` up in scope (outside the function), or pass it into the function and continue to use `push` as I demonstrated.

Comment: I see, then I understand push now, so I will utilize that. I'm sure it can do what I need it to now.